# RaiseEvent not allowed

Tags: class, events, visual-studio-2015

I have the following class stated below.
I would like it to raise an event when it has finished computing.
However VS-2015 tells me "You may not reference an instance member of a class without an explicit instance of the classes' methods.".

Can anybody tell me what goes wrong here and how I can solve this problem?
I think every class can raise an event.

Thank you!

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports NAudio.Wave

Namespace VoiceRecorder.Audio

    Public Class AudioSaver

        Public Event Finished()

        Private _sInputPath As String

        Public Property _tsTrimFromStart As TimeSpan
        Public Property _tsTrimFromEnd As TimeSpan
        '  Public Property _sffSaveFileFormat As SaveFileFormat
        Public Property _sLameExePath As String

        Public Sub New(ByVal uInputPath As String)
            Me._sInputPath = uInputPath
        End Sub

        Public ReadOnly Property IsTrimNeeded As Boolean
            Get
                Return _tsTrimFromStart <> TimeSpan.Zero OrElse _tsTrimFromEnd <> TimeSpan.Zero
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Sub SaveAudio(ByVal uOutputPath As String)

            Dim sTempFiles As New List(Of String)
            Dim sPathToProcess = _sInputPath
            If IsTrimNeeded() Then
                Dim sTempFile As String = WavFileUtils.GetTempWavFileName()
                sTempFiles.Add(sTempFile)
                WavFileUtils.TrimWavFile(_sInputPath, sTempFile, _tsTrimFromStart, _tsTrimFromEnd)
                sPathToProcess = sTempFile
            End If

            '   If _sffSaveFileFormat = SaveFileFormat.Mp3 Then
            ConvertToMp3(Me._sLameExePath, sPathToProcess, uOutputPath)
                'Else
                '    File.Copy(sPathToProcess, uOutputPath, True)
                'End If
                DeleteTempFiles(sTempFiles)
        End Sub

        Private Sub DeleteTempFiles(ByVal tempFiles As IEnumerable(Of String))
            For Each tempFile In tempFiles
                If File.Exists(tempFile) Then
                    File.Delete(tempFile)
                End If
            Next tempFile
        End Sub

        Public Shared Sub ConvertToMp3(ByVal lameExePath As String, ByVal waveFile As String, ByVal mp3File As String)

            Dim nConverter = Process.Start(lameExePath, "-V2 """ & waveFile & """ """ & mp3File & """")
            nConverter.WaitForExit()

            RaiseEvent Finished()

        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I had to remove the "Shared" attribute, but I still don't know why that is so.